# ASP.NET Server Controls - Show Hide Textbox based on Dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, html

What is the best way to show/hide a textbox or an entire div section based on a users selection from a dropdown? I don't believe its possible with server controls, so I would have to use regular client side HTML controls, correct? Thanks for any input. Would jQuery be the best option for this? Is there a way to hide the Div by default and then show it when the user selects the option from the drop down?

```
<div id="divLimitPrice">Limit Price<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLimitPrice" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroupOrder"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLimitPrice" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLimitPrice" ErrorMessage="This is a required field."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[id*="ddPriceType"]').on('change', function () {
            var val = this.value,
                $divLimitPrice = $('[id*="divLimitPrice"]');

            if (val === 1 || val === 2) {
                // Hide div group
                $divLimitPrice.hide();
            } else {
                // Show div group
                $divLimitPrice.show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

 Price Type<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddPriceType" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroupOrder">
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text ="Select a Price Type" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" text="Type 2" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="3" text="Type 3" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="4" text="Type 4" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPriceType" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddPriceType" ErrorMessage="This is a required field."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <div id="divLimitPrice">Limit Price<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLimitPrice" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroupOrder"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLimitPrice" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLimitPrice" ErrorMessage="This is a required field."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>`
```

Hmm.. I tried adapting the code and I am missing something! Any thoughts? Thank you for your time.

Comment: using server controls you can accomplish the same behavior.

Comment: As the answers suggest, the best way to accomplish this would be on the client-side using jQuery. "Server controls" can mimic this behavior by toggling the .Visible property. For instance, you could toggle the .Visible property of an <asp:Panel> on the server side on the SelectedIndexChanged event of the <asp:DropDownList>. You could then wrap everything in UpdatePanels to make it seamless (AJAX).

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is impossible. You can do whatever you have asked in the question. There is no need to switch to normal HTML controls also. If you want to hide a textbox or div it does not matter. I will show you a simple sample with out aspx controls. Follow the same and you will get the result as u expected.

Check This Link

> [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tt92j/)

Here inside the div tags you can use any aspx control

```
<div>
<asp:textbox id="TxtSample" runat="server" />
</div>

Or Instead of DIV you can use Panels too

<asp:Panel ID="PnlLogin" runat="server">
 -- --  Your Controls Here
</asp:panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.jquery` for that .

```
$(function () {
    $('[id*="dropdown"]').on('change', function () {
        var val = this.value,
            $txtbox = $('[id*="txtLimitPrice"]');

        if (val === 1 || val === 2) {
            // Hide text box
            $txtbox.hide();
        } else {
            // Show text box
            $txtbox.show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you guys, very helpful, appreciate it.